# PDO Quote problems

Tags: pdo, quote

i have a problem, and i can't undertstand why, i'am also new on php, in any case the problem is if i for example want send an email with php,

```
$email=$con->quote($_POST['Email']); 
$to = "$email";
$subject = "example";
$message = "example";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$mail= mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
```

This don't work, but if i write `$email=$_POST['Email'];`
This work, and i can't understand why, i prefer work with a quoted variable, for avoid sql injection. Thanks in advice, have a good day!

Comment: you should forget about `quote()` and use prepared statements

Comment: can you please exaple me how? thanks in advice!